# Unable to download Video file in WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-download-manager

When I click the link in WebView then video downloading is started but the format of video is unknown, due to which Android is not playing the downloaded video file. 
Also, when I download the video from the same link in chrome then video download in correct format and android is able to play the video file.

```
        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web1);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.loadUrl("my url");

    webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {


        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Game of thrones ");
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: show the code how you are doing it

Comment: seems to be the exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549750/android-downloadmanager-impossible-to-open-file

Comment: yes, just testing.